# pyproject correct way to import parent

Tags: python, import, pyproject.toml

I am trying to follow the correct way to import files in python but I can't make it works.
This is my project :

```
import_test/
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── bar.py
│   │   ├── baz
│   │   │   ├── baz.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

**what I want :** I want to call bar.py from main.py and I want to call main.py from baz.py
**how I did it** :
this is my pyproject :

```ini
[project]
name = "import_test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "testing import"
```

main.py :

```py
from import_test.bar import bar
var_from_main = 0
print(bar)
```

bar.py :

```py
bar = 2
```

baz.py :

```py
from import_test.main import var_from_main
print(var_from_main)
```

**this is the result I have** :

```bash
> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_test/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from import_test.bar import *
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_test'
> python foo/bar/baz/baz.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_test/foo/bar/baz/baz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from import_test.main import var_from_main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_test'
```

Comment: You need to put all Python code inside an `import_test` directory, this will be your top-level import package, so you can do imports such as `import import_test.foo` or `from import_test import foo`. -- I even recommend using a so-called `src`-layout and follow this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/